# Cannot migrate IdentityModels.cs [macOS]

Tags: asp.net, macos, authentication, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

Visual Studio for Mac does not automatically add the code for user authentication. I created a new MVC web application and I copied and pasted the IdentityModel.cs file from another project that someone made on Windows. I added it into my models.

I then cd'ed into my project directory and ran the command:
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

But I get the error:
No DbContext was found in assembly 'Vidly'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic

I think I have to call create() somewhere to fix it but I have no idea where it should go. Please help me.

```
public class IdentityModels
    {
        // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {

            public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
            {
                // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
                var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                // Add custom user claims here
                return userIdentity;
            }
        }

        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection",throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
            }

            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s <YouStartupProject> -p <YourDBContextProject>`. You have to tell command which is your startup project and for which project you are adding migration.

Comment: Name of project is testmvc. I did: dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s testmvc-p testmvc
I got: No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Comment: Are you using multiple projects?

Comment: No just the testmvc project

Comment: Which EF Core version you have?

Comment: 6.2.0 version of entityframework, 2.1.0 version of entityframework core

Comment: Is Vidly the assembly that contains your DBContext?